# A property of discrete spaces

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be some topological space and consider the set $\mathfrak{P}_0(X)$ of non-void subsets of $X$. We will endow this set with the coarsest topology such that, for any closed subset $A \subset X$, $\mathfrak{P}_0(A)$ is a closed subset of $\mathfrak{P}_0(X)$. Another way to put this is by saying that if we call a set of the form $\complement \mathfrak{P}_0(\complement A)$ elementary when $A$ is an open subset of $X$, then the finite intersections of elementary set are a basis of the topology we consider (any open set is a union of such finite intersections).

Let $i : X \to \mathfrak{P}_0(X)$ be the map $x \mapsto \{x\}$. It is easy to see that $i$ is a homeomorphism onto $i(X)$. Indeed it is continuous because of the formulae $i^{-1} (\cap A_\alpha)=\cap i^{-1}(A_\alpha)$ and $i^{-1}(\mathfrak{P}_0(A))=A$. It is open because of the formulae $i(A)=i(X)\cap \complement \mathfrak{P}_0(\complement A)$.

I'm interested in the closure of $i(X)$. If $X$ is a discrete space, then $i(X)$ is a closed subset of $\mathfrak{P}_0(X)$. Indeed, if $B \subset X$ belongs to the closure of $i(X)$ and contains more than just one element (i.e. $B \notin i(X)$), say $x$ and $x'$, consider the closed subsets of $X$
$$ \{x\}, \{x'\}, X\setminus \{x,x'\} $$
and call them $A_1,A_2,A_3$. The union of these set is $X$, so that 
$$ i(X) \subset \bigcup_{1 \leq i \leq 3} \mathfrak{P}_0(A_i) $$
plus, the $A_i$ are closed, so the right-hand side is closed. We get that $B$ must belong to this right hand side, which is impossible.

I've tried to prove that, conversely, if $i(X)$ is closed then $X$ must be a discrete space, but with no success. Maybe this is false. Do you have any guess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ be a topological space. For each $U\in\tau$ let $U^*=\{A\in\wp_0(X):A\cap U\ne\varnothing\}$; then $\{U^*:U\in\tau\}$ is a subbase for your topology on $\wp_0(X)$. Now suppose that $A\subseteq X$ has at least two points, say $x\ne y$. If $x$ and $y$ have disjoint open nbhds $U_x$ and $U_y$, respectively, then $U_x^*\cap U_y^*$ is an open nbhd of $A$ in $\wp_0(X)$ that is disjoint from $i[X]$. Thus, $i[X]$ is closed in $\wp_0(X)$ whenever $X$ is Hausdorff.

**Added:** Suppose now that $X$ is not Hausdorff, let $x$ and $y$ be points of $X$ that cannot be separated by disjoint open sets, and let $A=\{x,y\}$. Any open nbhd of $A$ in $\wp_0(X)$ must contain a basic open nbhd of the form $\bigcap_{U\in\mathscr{U}}U^*$ for some finite $\mathscr{U}\subseteq\tau$, so let $\bigcap_{U\in\mathscr{U}}U^*$ be such a basic open nbhd of $A$ in $\wp_0(X)$; then $A\cap U\ne\varnothing$ for each $U\in\mathscr{U}$.

Let $U_x=\bigcap\{U\in\mathscr{U}:x\in U\}$ and $U_y=\bigcap\{U\in\mathscr{U}:y\in U\}$. If $U_x=\varnothing$, then $\{y\}\in i[X]\cap\bigcap_{U\in\mathscr{U}}U^*$, and if $U_y=\varnothing$, then $\{x\}\in i[X]\cap\bigcap_{U\in\mathscr{U}}U_x$. If $U_x\ne\varnothing\ne U_y$, then $U_x$ is an open nbhd of $x$, and $U_y$ is an open nbhd of $y$, so $U_x\cap U_y\ne\varnothing$. Fix $z\in U_x\cap U_y$; clearly $\{z\}\in i[X]\cap\bigcap_{U\in\mathscr{U}}U^*$. It follows that $A\in\big(\operatorname{cl}_{\wp_0(X)}i[X]\big)\setminus i[X]$ and hence that $i[X]$ is not closed in $\wp_0(X)$. Thus, $i[X]$ is closed in $\wp_0(X)$ if and only if $X$ is Hausdorff.

Comment: BrianM.Scott, $X$ being Hausdorff is sufficient, but I could only show that $X$ being Fréchet is necessary (I mistakenly thought that I've shown it's equivalent). Can you bridge the gap?

Comment: @Jonathan: $X$ being Fréchet can’t be a necessary condition, since it’s not implied by $X$ being Hausdorff. In fact it turns out that Hausdorffness of $X$ is necessary and sufficient.

Comment: As to the latter, perfect! As to the former, really (I'm confused)?

Comment: @Jonathan: A Fréchet space is one in which a set is closed if and only if it’s sequentially closed; this doesn’t really have much to do with separation properties.

Comment: I meant $T_1$. Perhaps I'm confusing the terminology.

Comment: @Jonathan: Wikipedia tells me that some people do use the term *Fréchet space* to mean $T_1$ *space*, but in over $40$ years of doing topology I don’t recall having encountered the usage.

Comment: ;). Since I can't for the life of me keep separation axioms straight in my head, that's exactly where I got the term for $T_1$.